# facebook iframe app - how to organize and write code for faster page loading - PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, http-headers, facebook-php-sdk

I am writing an app within a facebook iframe and am unsure how best to write this.  I originally wrote all the code within the main canvas.php file but found everything was running too slow before results were being loaded into the iframe.

I then tried using the php header location method so to try and load different pages into the iframe, thus reducing page load time.  However, the header location is ignored.

I have also tried using javascript to get the page to load within the iframe instead, this does load in the new page but the page experiences lots of problems.  It wil not pass parrameteres to itself using $_GET.

Basically, I need to perform some checks when the canvas page is first loaded in the iframe and then re-direct to another file to avoid the checks being perfomed on every page load as this seriously shows everything down.  I then need to have page reloads with different parrameteres in the URL to populate the iframe with different results, again this is very slow as it has to perfomr all the checks again.

Therefore, how can I achieve a smooth workflow as a normal site within a facebook iframe?

[EDIT]  Just thought is Ajax a valid option?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most people experience slow response times due to not having a channelURL specified.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

> Channel File
>
> The channel file addresses some issues with cross domain communication
>   in certain browsers. The contents of the channel.html file can be just
>   a single line:
>
> It is important for the channel file to be cached for as long as
>   possible. When serving this file, you must send valid Expires headers
>   with a long expiration period. This will ensure the channel file is
>   cached by the browser which is important for a smooth user experience.
>   Without proper caching, cross domain communication will become very
>   slow and users will suffer a severely degraded experience. A simple
>   way to do this in PHP is:
>
> The channelUrl parameter is optional, but recommended. Providing a
>   channel file can help address three specific known issues. First,
>   pages that include code to communicate across frames may cause Social
>   Plugins to show up as blank without a channelUrl. Second, if no
>   channelUrl is provided and a page includes auto-playing audio or
>   video, the user may hear two streams of audio because the page has
>   been loaded a second time in the background for cross domain
>   communication. Third, a channel file will prevent inclusion of extra
>   hits in your server-side logs. If you do not specify a channelUrl, you
>   can remove page views containing fb_xd_bust or fb_xd_fragment
>   parameters from your logs to ensure proper counts.
>
> The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on
>   which you include the SDK. In other words, the channel file domain
>   must include www if your site is served using www, and if you modify
>   document.domain on your page you must make the same document.domain
>   change in the channel.html file as well. The protocols must also
>   match. If your page is served over https, your channelUrl must also be
>   https. Remember to use the matching protocol for the script src as
>   well. The sample code above uses protocol-relative URLs which should
>   handle most https cases properly.